# How to remove the url and footer in the Jquery PrintElement 

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

[plugin link](http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/Sample/)

I am using the above plugin to print a part of the web page, My query here is how to remove the url and footer that is been displayed along with the print page, i.e., marked with red color in the image shown below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isn't this default behaviour of your browser? within chrome you could say to remove the header an footer

Comment: m just taking print of a web page bro, i don't want the url path along with the print page