# How to move the date position from top to bottom in "Print PDF" page?

Tags: javascript, css, pdf, printing

How to "move" the date position from top to bottom in "Print PDF" page?

Is it possible with css or javascript? (please note: my question is not "how to remove header & footer")

[image: screenshot: print pdf page with chrome browser]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the url and footer in the Jquery PrintElement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034354/how-to-remove-the-url-and-footer-in-the-jquery-printelement)

Comment: Please show us the code that you have tried.

Comment: Its just common contents in the <table> not used any special codes for customizing the print pdf page

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are trying to print some web page content from browser print option.

Browser adds header / footer. Position of header (date, url, etc...) is browser specific. In Google Chrome it can be only enabled or disabled (maybe there are formatting options inside Chrome settings) in Firefox content of header/footer can be customized in print options.

Comment: ok.. thatz fine but couldn't move the date from top to bottom?